# Is there a way with Python + Pandas to save small chunk files individually?

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to programming and I'm currently trying to breakdown a CSV file into bite-sized chunks and saving those chunks as individual files. I was able to do it using a super roundabout way but now I want to figure out how to write a function that does this for me.
This is the code I have now:

```
import pandas as pd

def chunky(file, chunksize, iterator, rounds):
  df = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize = chunksize, iterator = iterator)
  count = 0
  while count < rounds:
    count += 1
    file = next(df)
    file.to_csv("output.csv")
```

However, when I do this it will print the output as one file but I am looking to save multiple individual files. Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: First amend your question with *how* you want to subdivide your dataframe? One column per new file? One row per new file? A file every 10 rows? Every 100 rows? Something else entirely?

Comment: Also, since you leave the `iterator` keyword open whether it's True or False, there are two routes you need to take, depending on what `iterator` is. When True, you use `get_chunk`, when False, you don't.

Comment: You should give examples of what values `chunksize` are (perhaps it's even `None`), what size your CSV files etc.

Comment: "it will print the output as one file": because you only specify one output file.